# arguments in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

this script moves all the doc files to a specified directory....i have managed to put an argument but the problem im facing is puting the full path where the scripts are moving to for example i want to run the script like this below

```
./loo -d then path where im moving the files (i.e ./loo -d the second argument where files are moving to)
```

this is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
From="/home/elg19/lone/doc"
To="/home/elg19/documents"

if [ $1 = -d ]; then
cd "$From"
for i in pdf txt doc; do
find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$To" \;
done
fi
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You know `$1`, so using `$2` doesn't really sound like a challenge for you. Could you try and explain better what you are missing?

Comment: when i use $2 its not working maybe im making a mistake somewhere but if you can help me on where i can insert $2 in my code i guess i will understand better

Comment: Post the code you have tried, and explain precisely the error/problem it is giving.

Comment: find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$2" \;

Comment: "and explain precisely the error/problem it is giving"

Comment: its not moving the files but running without errors

Comment: Give us an example of how you use it, including the real directory names you are using. Ideally, please copy and paste all the text from your console.

Comment: the usual way of running a script on the terminal is ./scriptname right but i later introduced the argument -d so if i put ./scriptname it will not run but if i put ./scriptname -d it will now i want to put another argument for the path(where the files are moving in this case "/home/elg19/documents") such that when i do not include the path it wont run but if i put ./scriptname -d path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

from=/home/elg19/lone/doc
if [[ $1 = -d ]]; then
    to=$2
else
    to=/home/elg19/documents
fi

find "$from" -type f \( -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.doc' \) -exec bash -c 'dest=$1; shift; mv "$@" "$dest"' _ "$to" {} +
```

Comment: sorry I forgot that when using + you need to put the braces at the end, I've edited the answer to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the exact problem?

Do you need to put a `"` around full path if it contains spaces?
       `./loo -d "full path with spaces"`
Similary to $1, full path can be retrieved with $2.

Comment: i discovered i can use the $2 but where in the script can i put it?